# MySQL Database structure for storing which files and how many times a user downloads?

Tags: php, mysql, database, structure

I'm creating a database that will store how many times a user downloads a media file, and also what media files a user has downloaded (Based on IP, no login required). I'm just not sure the correct structure for a MySQL database.

I already have a database with all the media files, so counting won't be an issue, but I also want to be able to see who downloaded the file. I would be using PHP to retrieve the content, but I'm not sure how to get it most efficiently. So something like: *"XYZ.mp3 has 20 downloads. [IMN CMS] *Click* XYZ.mp3 has been downloaded by 1.2.3.4 four times and sixteen other IPs"*

Also, I would want to be able to see that 1.2.3.4 has listened to XYZ.mp3 four times, and HWM.mp3 one time, and ... etc.

Further more, I would eventually like to know how much of the mp3 files they have listened to. (There is a built in player on my site) I also want this to be to where I can see that so many people have listened to so much based on the file, or that this user has listened to this file this much.

I know how to do the how many times count, as said before, but I'm not sure how to most efficiently structure the second part so that the data can be quickly gathered.

Also, the amount of files grows linearly weekly, and eventually it will become a very large number, so I'm not sure if having 200 columns (right now) that expands as necessary is the way to go? I don't expect a large user base, but you never know. I don't want to have to restructure and recode later because it does.

Thanks for the help, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Keep in mind that over time different users might use the same IP address to download files. So you not only want to store the IP but also in which time-frame that happened (if you do not also identify a user with some random token cookie for example).

Comment: @hakre, that's a good idea.

Comment: @ethrbunny, that would be a column for each file and would be filled as a user downloaded. Obviously a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me I'd have 3 tables:

1. **connections** - keep IP and session id with some unique connection id.
2. **downloads** - keep file id, and connection id. This lets you know how many times a file has been downloaded and by which connection.
3. **plays** - keep file id, connection id and file dl %. Use `http partial content` to track how much of each file has been played by a given connection id.

Between these three you can build stats for what you're asking for.

Comment: So the connections table would just hold who has downloaded with cookie IDs? What about when somebody clears their cookies, how do I deal with that? The downloads will keep what files, what who, but how do I correctly log that 300 people have downloaded a file, while still being able to quickly find that 1.2.3.4 has downloaded that file? Would I do a sorted text field? What if the allotted character space ends up being too small? Plays seems to be simple, but if a user downloads more than once, how would I best log those multiple numbers?

Comment: Session var would come from PHP - to define one login of 1.2.3.4 vs another. Each dl of a file gets a row. To find total for a file just count. To find total for an IP do a join by connection id and count.

Comment: Is there a way to be able to tell if a person's cookies have been cleared? Or could it end up being that I'll have 100 unique visitors from the same person?

Comment: doesn't matter if cookies get cleared. the session var just gives you a notion of a 'unique' login. it might not (over space and time) be 100% guaranteed unique but you can generate a GUID or similar if that's what you need. Heck - the auto_increment connection ID will do this for you.

Comment: Okay, but the session ID is meant to be long term?
Would you know any tutorials that show how to do what you're talking about?

Comment: Let me rephrase #1 above - forget session ID. Just log IP with a time/date stamp and an auto_increment 'connection id' field. This gives you a unique login value. Use this to index / join with #2 and #3. mySQL gives you this for free in your table def.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would do the following:

**1.** I would give each file an id number which mysql can auto increment.

**2.** Then I would create another table in which ip and the id of the file that the user has downloaded is stored.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, makes sense, but how do I efficiently record that 1.2.3.4 has listened to twenty files? Furthermore, how do I quickly recover that they're on the list that has listened to XYZ.mp3?

Comment: To tackle this problem whenever you need to find out this you could write a simple PHP program that communicates with mysql to get all the things that 1.2.3.4 has listened to. But what exactly are you planning to do with that information? Are you planning to display the info on a profile page or something?

Comment: It would just be for tracking/seeing what people are listening to.
Might it be better to duplicate data? So that in the user table, 1.2.3.4 has listened to XYZ, ZYX, YZY, WHB, JPW, CDA.... and then on each of those in the files table I would have on each of those that 1.2.3.4 listened to them? Then XYZ might have 1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8 and so on? I don't like having duplicate data like that, but would that be the most efficient way?

Comment: Yes that could work, but if I were you I would just stick to having one a table that links the user id to the id of the file however if you wish to do what you have said; it also could work.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding how you'd link them together then. Would you please try to explain?

Comment: give each user an id and give each file an id. just have one table named 'listens' or something and have the colums: id (of the listen), men_id (id of the user), file_id(id of the file) then if you want to get the info just write some code that gets the amount of rows in the table where the mem_id is whatever the id of the user is and the file_id is the id of the file